# 2 Kings 17:38 Do not fear (or worship?) other gods

Tags: 2-kings, worship

worship
תִֽירְא֖וּ (ṯî·rə·’ū)
Verb - Qal - Imperfect - second person masculine plural
Strong's Hebrew 3372: To fear, to revere, caus, to frighten

In https://biblehub.com/2_kings/17-38.htm, 19 of 26 versions translate it as *fear* while the rest translate it as *worship*. What is the meaning here in Hebrew?

> Luke 12:5 But I will show you whom you should fear: Fear him who, after your body has been killed, has authority to throw you into hell. Yes, I tell you, fear him.

Comment: The literal meaning of תִֽירְא֖וּ is without a doubt "fear". The ones who translate as "worship" are not entirely wrong however, since "do not fear the gods" can also be interpreted as "do not worship them".

Comment: I agree with @Bach - both are correct, one literal and the other slightly more interpretive.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure if this is the answer you’re looking for but I agree with @Bach, the literal meaning is fear.

However it’s not the sort of fear as we would generally think of today, in the bible fear of God is a healthy fear which prevents one from following a wrong course.

Proverbs 8:13 -
“The fear of the LORD is to hate evil”

So in line with this thought, at 2 Kings 17:37 God was commanding them not follow the customs or laws of the others gods, and not to fear displeasing them but to worship him alone - Ex 20:5.

Comment: Hi LT347, welcome to BH.SE - thanks for contributing! This looks like the basis of a good answer - I suspect you could add a lot more substance here to explain your rationale and justify this view more clearly. Hope to see more from you - please do take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out more about the site and how things work here.